Definition of annuity
To my understanding, an annuity is a contract you make with, let's say, an insurance company. You pay the principal and they commit to pay you regularly a certain for a period of time, which might be until your death.
My problems come with the regular payments and the goal of an annuity. I am very new to finance so take my questions with a grain of salt.
Are the regular payments supposed to give you back the principal (and maybe an interest) when the annuities stop? Contrary to a bond, it is not clear to me if you are supposed to get all your money back at the end. I have only seen that you get regular payments. If they are huge yes, if they are small why pay for the contract?
From what I understand naively, either it is

a service you pay for them to keep the money and make you payments later, when you might need it, so you are guaranteed to lose some money,
an investment you make, which is supposed to give your money back at the end, the risk being that the insurance company fails before it happens,
an investment you make, but depending on the income you will get, you might lose or win money at the end.

Is one of the three somewhat close to reality?
What is the discount rate, or the interest rate that is used for the computation of the present value of an annuity (see here for example)? Does it have anything to do with the regular payment?

This question is similar to: Understanding annuities with respect to Term Life insurance. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's closest to 2, though the risk of the insurance company failing is not typically a consideration. You certainly get more back in most cases, though there are variable annuities where you might get back less, which would be closer to #3

@littleadv I indeed believe it is different given my 3rd question. The first two questions are answered here aswell as in your link though.

It's mostly a form of insurance. You don't know how long you're going to live in retirement (could be 5 years, could be 40). You don't know what your investments are going to do. Your spending is going to be very different if your pension has to last 5 years or has to last 40 years. And you don't know in advance which it's going to be. So you buy an annuity instead, which gives you certainty over how much income you can spend every year, and the insurance company takes on the risk (and reward) of you living longer or shorter than expected.

It's essentially 3.  But it's also a risk-transfer exercise.
A common type of annuity is a pension for life.  You save money in a pension fund while you are working.  So when you retire, you have a big lump sum of money that you hope will last you for the rest of your life.  But you don't know how long you're going to live, and you don't know how well your pension fund will do for the next 10 to 30 years.
You could leave the money invested, and take a monthly drawdown.  Take too little and the fund keeps growing while you live in poverty.  Take too much and the money runs out before you die.
Alternatively, hand over the whole pension pot to an insurance company and buy an annuity.  In return, they guarantee you a pension for the rest of your life.  If you die next year, they keep your money.  If you live until you are 100, then they have to keep paying.

Is it the same idea with annuities that stop after 10 years ? Are the insurance company betting that you will die before the 10 years, and if not you will get your money back plus a bonus ?

The difference between a pension program and a savings account is that you aren't limited to what you put it with regard to what you might eventually receive. It's up to the pension manager to ensure that the payments they entitled you to are available, by having current workers pay in more than you receiving and/or by investing the money and using the growth to cover your "gains".

@raisinsec For annuities with a fixed duration, the insurance companies are betting that the interest they get by investing your money will be more than the interest they pay to you.

Annuities protect you against dying too late, but also dying too early: nearly all annuities have some sort of death benefit, so they don't "keep your money". At minimum, the current value is returned. A life insurance-like benefit may guarantee a minimum return or payout, exceeding investment returns. A period certain annuity guarantees a minimum payout period, which goes to your estate. This was important as a one-stop-shop investment in a past era.

@user71659 That depends on your situation. The “normal” terms are “we pay a fixed monthly amount maybe adjusted by inflation until you die”. If you want more, the monthly payment will be less. If you are married, you may want an annuity that pays as long as you and your spouse live. If you have no children you may have no interest in leaving any money behind.

In brief, with an annuity you are purchasing a guaranteed income stream at a constant rate even if you outlive the initial principal and the returns upon it. The insurance company, looking at their actuarial tables, is betting that you do not outlive the money and/or that they can make enough profit investing it to more than pay for the payments they make to you, either of which represents profit to them.
I purchased an annuity with about 5% of my retirement investments, to give myself a higher guaranteed income stream then Social Security. (And perhaps a better guaranteed one, if certain politicians ever have their way, though I honestly believe their threats are mostly fear tactic campaigning father than reality.) But it's a small amount because it is just a safety net and reassurance; I believe I will do better by simply keeping my money invested until I need it.

The insurance company is not really betting on your individual lifespan, but on the distribution of lifespans of all their customers that buy annuities from them in the expectation that some will dies early and others late.

@Henry: points granted, I was oversimplifying. Read "you" as "all of you."

Imagine if planting a $20 bill sprouted a money tree, which yields $1 every year, forever. Then $20 today is worth the same as $1 every year, forever. The fraction of its cost a tree yields annually is the discount rate i.
In real life, money doesn't grow on trees, and building a money factory has been known to attract federal agents. Annuity is a legal way to make this trade.
An annuity has no principal. The money you've invested no longer exists for you; all you have now is a tree, which you can harvest annually.
There are different kinds of annuities:

A perpetuity never expires, yielding that i forever;
A regular annuity is a money tree that lives N years;
A life annuity is a money tree that dies with you.

The discount rate, in all cases, is the average return of a theoretical zero-risk investment. Annuities with a limited lifespan are expected to pay more the discount rate.
A life annuity is a bet on your lifespan - you're betting you'll live longer than N, the company less, where N is how many years a competing fixed term annuity with the same yield would last.
Should you live forever, the company has sold you a perpetuity for the price of an annuity.
To give examples, the fair present value of a $10,000/year annuity at a 5% discount rate is:

$200,000 for a perpetuity
$124,622 for a 20-year annuity
$77,217 for a 10-year annuity

Thus, if a company sells you a life annuity of $10,000 for $125,000, they're staking $75,000 (their maximum loss if you do live forever), with an over/under at 20 years, to win up to $125,000 if you depart before the first payment. You're betting $125,000 that you'll live for more than 20 years from now, winning $10,000 for each year that you do.

Annuities are also insurance for insurance companies. If you sell life insurance and people start dying earlier (e.g. due to Covid), then you have a problem. But if you are also selling annuities, then the extra money you have to pay out for life insurance will be offset by the money you’re saving on annuity payments.
